# Setting a method as the onclick action of a button from within the constructor of a class

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner so please don't get mad. This class is for making cards, my goal is to set the save button to disable all the input areas and the edit button to enable them, however when I try to set these buttons to their respective methods (from within the constructor) an error comes up. Please help.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Manage.css">
    <title>Manage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="logout" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Logout</button>
    <!-- <button id="edit" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" ">Edit</button> -->
    <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="new Card()">Add</button>
    <button id="del" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>



    <div id="cards">


    </div>

        <script src="Manage1.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
var cards = document.getElementById("cards")
var x = 1



class Card {
    constructor() {
        this.card = document.createElement("div");
        this.card.classList.add("cards__item");

        this.teacher = document.createElement("input");
        this.teacher.classList.add("Teacher");
        this.teacher.setAttribute("placeholder","Teacher's name");
        this.card.appendChild(this.teacher);


        this.code = document.createElement("input");
        this.code.classList.add("Code");
        this.code.setAttribute("placeholder","Subject code");
        this.card.appendChild(this.code);


        this.startTime = document.createElement("input");
        this.startTime.setAttribute("type","time");
        // this.startTime.classL    ist.add("startTime")
        this.card.appendChild(this.startTime);


        this.endTime = document.createElement("input");
        this.endTime.setAttribute("type","time");
        // this.startTime.classList.add("startTime")
        this.card.appendChild(this.endTime);
        

        this.info = document.createElement("input");
        this.info.setAttribute("type", "text");
        this.card.appendChild(this.info);

        this.moreInfo = document.createElement("button");
        this.moreInfo.innerHTML = "More info"
        this.moreInfo.classList.add("btn")
        this.moreInfo.classList.add("btn-primary")
        this.card.appendChild(this.moreInfo)


        this.save = document.createElement("button");
        this.save.innerHTML = "save";
        this.save.classList.add("btn")
        this.save.classList.add("btn-danger")
        this.save.classList.add("btn-primary");
        this.save.addEventListener("click",this.saveCard)
        this.card.appendChild(this.save)


        this.edit = document.createElement("button");
        this.edit.innerHTML = "Edit";
        this.edit.classList.add("btn")
        this.edit.classList.add("btn-secondary")
        this.edit.addEventListener("click",this.editCard())



        
        this.card.appendChild(this.edit)
        cards.appendChild(this.card)
    }


    saveCard(){
        this.teacher.disabled = true;
        this.code.disabled = true;
        this.startTime.disabled = true;
        this.endTime.disabled = true;
        this.info.disabled = true;
    }

    editCard(){
        this.teacher.disabled = false;
        this.code.disabled = false;
        this.startTime.disabled = false;
        this.endTime.disabled = false;
        this.info.disabled = false;
    }

    // delete(){}
  }
```

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.teacher is undefined
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the error comes up when I click the "save" button

Comment: small suggestion : add a language identifier to highlight the html code and make it more readable. also add the html tag

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverFlow 
At first, I should say that no one goes crazy here. :)
He/She just can close the tab.=))

About your question.

#### Learn Yourself

If you want to learn it yourself, I invite you to `console.log()` your **`this`** in the `saveCard()` and then understand your problem and don't resume reading the answer. :))))

​​
And about answer:

#### A little tips

```js
this.save.addEventListener("click", this.saveCard);
```

What do you pass to the `this.saveCard`?!??!
FYI, here you are passing the `e` or `Event` to the function and here your event is clicking on `button` so you are passing your button.
and after log you'll see:

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-primary">
```

yes, This is button that you clicked on it :)

So, how we can access to the class `teacher` with `this` in the `saveCard` method?!?!?

#### Answer

you need here to `call` your function instead of set that as `eventListener` callback :)
just change your code and change from:

```html
this.save.addEventListener("click",this.saveCard)
```

to :

```html
this.save.addEventListener("click", () => this.saveCard());
```

Comment: In addition to my answer, don't forget to do this about `this.editCard()` too :)

Comment: Thank you it worked, why do I have to put an arrow function though? Can you clarify that?